# Image not appearing in ipython notebook when in a non-sub directory

Tags: image, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to display a png image in an ipython notebook from an absolute path `/Users/zhermes/[...]/image.png`, using the code

```
<img src="/Users/zhermes/[...]/image.png" style="width: 80%">
```

but it won't embed (it produces a broken image icon).  I've confirmed that the path is correct using:

```
In: print os.path.exists('/Users/zhermes/[...]/image.png')
Out: True
```

If I make a copy of the image in the local directory, i.e. : `./image.png`, then this works fine:

```
<img src="image.png" style="width: 80%">
```

similarly its fine if I have a local subdirectory like `./images/image.png`

What's going wrong here?

---

Edit: using `IPython.display.Image` *does* work, but I'd prefer to use markdown.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing `url` and `path`, `browser` and `kernel`,`localhost` and `server`.
Try imagining the server is on **AWS** with the kernel in a super computer on **rackspace** with chrome/firefox on your **laptop**.

`<img src="/Users/zhermes/[...]/image.png" style="width: 80%">` use a path instead of a URL, so don't work. `<img src="image.png" style="width: 80%">` use a URL, which by some magic of IPython is mapped to `current_working/image.png` directory (on AWS).

`IPython.display.Image` get the image on rackspace.

What you ask in Markdown would access file on your `laptop`. For security reason it is impossible, otherwise the all internet would have access to your all hard drive.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar situation in which my images or pdfs won't show up on my ipython notebook. Matt is right, the important part is that the local server that renders your notebook has access to the files you are trying to use.

In my case the directory where I have a project with notebooks looks like this:

```
.
├── LICENSE.txt
├── README.md
├── images
│   ├── conductor.png
│   └── simple-position-sensor.png
├── notebooks
│   ├── performance-characteristics.ipynb
│   ├── position-sensor.ipynb
│   ├── resistance-temperature-detectors.html
│   ├── resistance-temperature-detectors.ipynb
│   └── resistance-temperature-detectors.slides.html
├── pdfs
│   └── linear-approximation.pdf
└── scripts
    ├── interp1d.py
    └── numbered_eq.py
```

When I run `ipython notebook` inside the notebooks folder the images don't render (markdown or html). They do render, as in your case, with `IPython.display.Image`.

The solution is to run `ipython notebook` on the working directory that has all the files you need for the ipython notebook.

Comment: Thanks!  In your case, which directory do you mean?  The notebook should run in the root directory `.`?

Comment: Yes, in this case it is the root directory ``.``, but in general run it in the folder that has the notebook and all supplementary files.